# Glitchy/freezing Logitch MX Keys and MX Master on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard, logitech-unifying-receiver

I have recently put together a desktop PC (Aorus B450I motherboard) with Windows 10, using the MX Keys and MX Master mouse/keyboard that I previously used on a Macbook Pro. (They never showed these problems there).

I'm finding both to be very unreliably glitchy.

If connected by Bluetooth, the mouse just completely stops working from time to time. If I open the Bluetooth Options dialog, it instantly fixes it. (I don't need to actually do anything there).

If connected by Logitech Unifying Receiver, the mouse behaves fine for a while, then starts randomly freezing, stuttering etc, then might be fine for a while.

The keyboard behaviours include:

- no keys registering at all
- backspace not registering
- pressing Esc registering as a toggle between Fn keys and media keys

I haven't noticed a clear relationship between keyboard behaviours and whether it's connected by Bluetooth or Unifying Receiver. Overall, the problems via Bluetooth seem more manageable than with Unifying Receiver.

It's very frustrating. I'm not sure what I can look at to fix it. There doesn't seem to be drivers that I can update for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was caused by interference/poor wireless connection. Moving the Unifying Receiver dongle to a USB extension cable, right next to the devices in question, seems to have totally fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I run windows 10 and I tried all the suggested fixes I found around the web none of which worked so I figured it was something to do with using the Bluetooth connectivity and so I just plugged in the unifying receiver and changed the mouse to use that.  It worked flawlessly.

After confirming this worked, I removed the dongle, changed the mouse back to the Bluetooth setting and it continued working fine.

So,switching to the Unifying Receiver and then back to a Bluetooth connection made the issues go (and stay) away.

Comment: This is a professional site: use professional language.